# Set border color to an Entry when is focused

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, uwp, effects

I am trying to set a border color to an Entry element so that it will be displayed on the Windows platform. To achieve this I have added an Effect to the project but when using the BorderBrush property it does not keep the color chosen for the Focused state. Instead it changes to the Windows emphasis color. You would need to control the color in all states of the control.

***MainPage.xaml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:effects="clr-namespace:XamarinTestApp.Effects"
             x:Class="XamarinTestApp.MainPage">

    <StackLayout Margin="20,100,20,0" >
        <Label Text="Input element" />
        <Entry x:Name="InputEntry">
            <Entry.Effects>
                <effects:EntryEffect />
            </Entry.Effects>
        </Entry>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

***EntryEffect.cs in common code***

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace XamarinTestApp.Effects
{
    public class EntryEffect : RoutingEffect
    {
        public EntryEffect() : base("EffectGroup.EntryEffect") { }
    }
}
```

***EntryEffect.cs in UWP code***

```
using Effects;
using System;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP;

[assembly: ResolutionGroupName("EffectGroup")]
[assembly: ExportEffect(typeof(EntryEffect), "EntryEffect")]
namespace Effects
{
    public class EntryEffect : PlatformEffect
    {
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            try
            {
                var control = Control as Control;
                var color = Color.Magenta.ToWindowsColor();
                control.BorderBrush = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.SolidColorBrush(color);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        
        }

        protected override void OnDetached() { }
    }
}
```

The same problem happens to me when it is in Hover state.
Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add Style in file `App.xaml` in uwp , just as follows:

```
<Application.Resources>
     <ResourceDictionary>
         <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextControlBorderBrushFocused" Color="Red"/>
    
         <Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="CustomTextBox">
             <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlForeground}" />
             <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBackground}" />
             <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderBrush}" />
             <Setter Property="SelectionHighlightColor" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlSelectionHighlightColor}" />
             <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderThemeThickness}" />
             <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
             <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
             <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Auto" />
             <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode" Value="Auto" />
             <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden" />
             <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden" />
             <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled" Value="False" />
             <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemePadding}" />
             <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="{ThemeResource IsApplicationFocusVisualKindReveal}" />
             <Setter Property="ContextFlyout" Value="{StaticResource TextControlCommandBarContextFlyout}" />
             <Setter Property="SelectionFlyout" Value="{StaticResource TextControlCommandBarSelectionFlyout}" />
             <Setter Property="Template">
                 <Setter.Value>
                     <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                         <Grid>
    
                             <Grid.Resources>
                                 <Style x:Name="DeleteButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
                                     <Setter Property="Template">
                                         <Setter.Value>
                                             <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                                 <Grid x:Name="ButtonLayoutGrid"
                                             BorderBrush="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonBorderBrush}"
                                             BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                             Background="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonBackground}">
    
                                                     <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                         <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                             <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
    
                                                             <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                                                 <Storyboard>
                                                                     <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonLayoutGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                                         <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                                                                     </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                     <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonLayoutGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                                         <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonBorderBrushPointerOver}" />
                                                                     </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                     <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="GlyphElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                                         <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                                                     </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                 </Storyboard>
                                                             </VisualState>
    
                                                             <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                                 <Storyboard>
                                                                     <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonLayoutGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                                         <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonBackgroundPressed}" />
                                                                     </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                     <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonLayoutGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                                         <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonBorderBrushPressed}" />
                                                                     </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                     <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="GlyphElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                                         <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonForegroundPressed}" />
                                                                     </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                 </Storyboard>
                                                             </VisualState>
    
                                                             <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                                                 <Storyboard>
                                                                     <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonLayoutGrid"
                                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                                 To="0"
                                                                 Duration="0" />
                                                                 </Storyboard>
                                                             </VisualState>
                                                         </VisualStateGroup>
                                                     </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                     <TextBlock x:Name="GlyphElement"
                                                 Foreground="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonForeground}"
                                                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                 HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                 FontStyle="Normal"
                                                 FontSize="12"
                                                 Text="&#xE10A;"
                                                 FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}"
                                                 AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" />
                                                 </Grid>
                                             </ControlTemplate>
                                         </Setter.Value>
                                     </Setter>
                                 </Style>
                             </Grid.Resources>
    
                             <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                 <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                     <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
    
                                     <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
    
                                         <Storyboard>
                                             <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                 <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlHeaderForegroundDisabled}" />
                                             </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                             <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                 <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundDisabled}" />
                                             </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                             <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                 <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderBrushDisabled}" />
                                             </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                             <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                 <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlForegroundDisabled}" />
                                             </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                             <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                 <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding PlaceholderForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, TargetNullValue={ThemeResource TextControlPlaceholderForegroundDisabled}}" />
                                             </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                         </Storyboard>
                                     </VisualState>
    
                                     <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
    
                                         <Storyboard>
                                             <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                 <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderBrushPointerOver}" />
                                             </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                             <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                 <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                                             </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                             <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                 <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding PlaceholderForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, TargetNullValue={ThemeResource TextControlPlaceholderForegroundPointerOver}}" />
                                             </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                             <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                 <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                             </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                         </Storyboard>
                                     </VisualState>
                                     <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
    
                                         <Storyboard>
                                             <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                 <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding PlaceholderForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, TargetNullValue={ThemeResource TextControlPlaceholderForegroundFocused}}" />
                                             </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                             <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                 <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundFocused}" />
                                             </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                             <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                 <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderBrushFocused}" />
                                             </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                             <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                 <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlForegroundFocused}" />
                                             </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                             <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RequestedTheme">
                                                 <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Light" />
                                             </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                         </Storyboard>
                                     </VisualState>
    
                                 </VisualStateGroup>
                                 <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ButtonStates">
                                     <VisualState x:Name="ButtonVisible">
    
                                         <Storyboard>
                                             <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DeleteButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                                 <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                     <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                         <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                     </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                 </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                             </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                         </Storyboard>
                                     </VisualState>
                                     <VisualState x:Name="ButtonCollapsed" />
    
                                 </VisualStateGroup>
    
                             </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    
                             <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                 <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                 <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                 <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                             </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    
                             <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                 <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                 <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                             </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    
                             <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter"
                         Grid.Row="0"
                         Grid.Column="0"
                         Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                         Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                         ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
                         FontWeight="Normal"
                         Foreground="{ThemeResource TextControlHeaderForeground}"
                         Margin="{ThemeResource TextBoxTopHeaderMargin}"
                         TextWrapping="Wrap"
                         VerticalAlignment="Top"
                         Visibility="Collapsed"
                         x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy" />
                             <Border x:Name="BorderElement"
                         Grid.Row="1"
                         Grid.Column="0"
                         Grid.RowSpan="1"
                         Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                         Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                         BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                         BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                         CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}"
                         Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True"
                         MinWidth="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinWidth}"
                         MinHeight="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinHeight}" />
                             <ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentElement"
                         Grid.Row="1"
                         Grid.Column="0"
                         HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}"
                         HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                         VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}"
                         VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                         IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}"
                         IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}"
                         IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}"
                         Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                         Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                         IsTabStop="False"
                         AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                         ZoomMode="Disabled" />
                             <TextBlock x:Name="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter"
                         Grid.Row="1"
                         Grid.Column="0"
                         Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                         Foreground="{Binding PlaceholderForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, TargetNullValue={ThemeResource TextControlPlaceholderForeground}}"
                         Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                         Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                         Text="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}"
                         TextAlignment="{TemplateBinding TextAlignment}"
                         TextWrapping="{TemplateBinding TextWrapping}"
                         IsHitTestVisible="False" />
                             <Button x:Name="DeleteButton"
                         Grid.Row="1"
                         Grid.Column="1"
                         Style="{StaticResource DeleteButtonStyle}"
                         BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                         Margin="{ThemeResource HelperButtonThemePadding}"
                         IsTabStop="False"
                         Visibility="Collapsed"
                         AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                         FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                         MinWidth="34"
                         VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
                             <ContentPresenter x:Name="DescriptionPresenter"
                         Grid.Row="2"
                         Grid.Column="0"
                         Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                         Content="{TemplateBinding Description}"
                         Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlDescriptionTextForegroundBrush}"
                         AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                         x:Load="False"/>
    
                         </Grid>
    
                     </ControlTemplate>
                 </Setter.Value>
             </Setter>
         </Style>
     </ResourceDictionary>
    
 </Application.Resources>
```

The `MyUwpRender` in uwp is:

```
 [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Entry), typeof(MyUwpRender))]
 namespace UwpApp1.UWP
 {
     public class MyUwpRender : EntryRenderer
     {
         public MyUwpRender()
         {
    
         }
         protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
         {
             base.OnElementChanged(e);
    
             if (Control != null)
             {
                // apply the style here
                 Control.Style = App.Current.Resources["CustomTextBox"] as Windows.UI.Xaml.Style;

                 // you can also change the CornerRadius here
                 Control.CornerRadius = new Windows.UI.Xaml.CornerRadius(5);
    
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you Jessie! It works! I only had to change the resource in OnAttached method (I am using Effects instead of Renderers) because I need it be dynamic. Your answer help me a lot!